# jQuery if/else Statement Fails

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I have this snippet of code that looks for the value in a select box on change and sets a html element with the jQuery .text, the first if statement in the following code seems to work, "Green" but the "Blue" if doesn't, Any ideas why?

```
$("#firstdrop").change(function() { 
    if ($("#firstdrop").val() == "Green") { 
        $('.price-tag').text('Green $5.00');
    } 
    if ($("#firstdrop").val() == "Blue") { 
        $('.price-tag').text('Blue $15.00');
    }        
});
```

Help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Nothing obvious jumps out. Post the HTML for your `<select>`.

Comment: Have you done something like `$("#firstdrop").val()` in the callback to see if the correct value comes through OK ?

Comment: @MattStrange .. You should use `this` as reference within the `change()` function.  `this` will reference `#firstdrop` but is an HTML DOM element.  If you want to convert to jQuery `var $this = $(this)` will do the trick.  In additon `.price-tag` may reference more than one element as it is a class selector.  For efficiency purposes you may want to add a tag name to the `.price-tag` selector.

Comment: Perhaps your item's value "Blue" may be list text, not list value.

Comment: Is this the correct use of `this` `$("#firstdrop").change(function() { 
 var $this = $(this)
 if ($("#firstdrop").val() == "Red") { 
        $('.price-tag').text('Green $5.00');
 
  } 
 if ($("#firstdrop").val() == "Select") { 
        $('.price-tag').text('Blue $15.00');
 
  }     
});`

Comment: Opps! just realised the value in the select box were different, my mistake. :p

Cheers guys for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/vMxWe/1/) for you to get the selected value from select.

```
<select id="firstdrop">
    <option value="-">-Select-</option>
    <option value="Green">Green</option>
    <option value="Blue" >Blue</option>
</select>
```

---

```
$('#firstdrop').change(function() { 
         var sel_value = $("#firstdrop option:selected").val(); 
         if (sel_value == 'Green') { 
            $('.price-tag').text('Green $5.00');
         } 
         if (sel_value == 'Blue') { 
            $('.price-tag').text('Blue $15.00');
         }
         if( sel_value == '-')
         {
            $('.price-tag').text('0');
         } 
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but shouldn't you use `this` as @John Hartsock mentioned in the .change function? I'm learning the jQuery and i must say it awesome!